# 同じページに対して2つのトランザクションがSIXロックを取得している？

Tags: sql-server

SQLServerの以下のデッドロックグラフがうまく解釈できません。

[image: deadlock]

(A)と(B)は、IDが同じなので、同一ページ（同一オブジェクト）と読み取れます。
更に、この同一のページに対して、プロセス363（左）とプロセス358（右上）がSIXロックを獲得していること（Owner Mode）も読み取れます。

[SIXロックは、SIXロックと互換性が無い](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/2014-toc/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2014#lock-compatibility)はずなので、2つのプロセス（トランザクション）が、同じページのSIXロックを既に獲得している、ということが不可解です。
どの部分の解釈が間違っているのでしょうか？

#### 環境の情報

- SQLServerのバージョンは2017

  - トランザクション分離レベルは READ COMMITTED
  - Is Read Committed Snapshot On = False
  - スナップショット分離を許可 = False